# Insomnia Github Push does nothing

Tags: git, github, insomnia

I am not the best at using Git but I cant figure out why pushing my Api from Insomnia to github does not work

I logged in my GitHub account and this appeared:

[image]

I used commit first (As you can see from the 3 commits I did)

First push was successful but nothing happened.

But when I press push again, I get an error

> Cannot parse remote url ""

That is probably implying that I have not set a repository url.

I entered the url again and nothing, so I decided to log out and Pull the project (In github there were just a .yml file)

[image]

When I tried to clone this project a new error came up

> Workspace New Document already exists. Please delete it before cloning

Clearly there is no document named New Document:

[image]

Am I missing something? Am I doing something wrong?

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue considering the remote url. But I got another Error, when changing the remote url, going back to the dashboard, opening the project again and trying to push my changes: HttpError: HTTP Error: 422 Unprocessable Entity.
Maybe its some unique bug in the version-control of insomnia? Creating an issue on their [Github Page](https://github.com/Kong/insomnia) might help.

Comment: plus-1, FWIW. How painful. :|